# Question abusively closed under the false pretext of lacking prior research

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I asked this question:

[Is there a DIY mechanical ventilator that saved the life of a COVID-19 patient? [closed]](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23134/is-there-a-diy-mechanical-ventilator-that-saved-the-life-of-a-covid-19-patient?noredirect=1#comment43566_23134)

I mention that despite my effort of more than one day I did not find an answer for it on the internet.

A moderator, Carey Gregory, commented that "it did lack prior research" and when asked by me to provide a link with the answer to my question his reply was "We're not a "google this for me" service" and he closed the topic.

I consider his attitude totally abusive, arrogant and incorrect as long as he was unable to give me even the slightest hint that would have made me find the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry you feel that way. If you want to lodge a complaint about me you should click the "Contact" link at the bottom of the page and send a message to the Community Moderation team (they are SE employees).

Comment: You really needed to show us that there was such a thing as a DIY ventilator.

Comment: Skeptics is another site that can answer questions like yours, but they will require you cite a reputable claim to post there. Requiring prior effort is pretty standard across SE sites.

Comment: A true DIY ventilator https://www.msnbc.com/mtp-daily/watch/doctor-creates-diy-ventilator-out-of-items-from-home-improvement-stores-81907269849

Answer (score 2):

First, let's note that you posted a comment on that question that was indeed quite rude and abusive to another member (not me). I deleted that comment and I admit it probably did negatively influence my attitude toward your question. I also admit that my "we're not a google this for me" comment was rude, so I've deleted it as well.

In another comment on the post, you said:

> A question lacking prior research means it already has an answer
>   somewhere else, which is easily accessible on the internet. I would
>   highly appreciate if you provide a link to such an answer.

No, that's not what lacking prior research means, and that's the specific thing that motivated my "google service" comment. We're not required to either allow your question or point you to the answer elsewhere. It also doesn't mean there's an answer out there; it simply means you didn't invest a sincere effort at trying to find the answer. If you read [the link](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-that-dont-show-any-research) given in the close notice, you'll see that the opening paragraph on the top-voted answer says this:

> To improve your chances of getting an answer, you need to demonstrate
>   that you’ve taken enough time to thoroughly search for an answer
>   before asking your question. This saves the site from reiterating
>   obvious answers and helps to get a more specific and relevant answers.

The answer goes on to give more concrete guidelines, which this site adopted as policy since shortly after its creation in 2015. That answer also cites [a broader question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-exchange-in-general-be-awarding-as-for-effort) for the entire SE network dating back to 2013 that essentially says the same thing.

You included a link to a youtube video about a company that quickly designed a ventilator and retooled a production line to produce it using motors they already make, but as several commenters noted, that's not an example of a DIY ventilator. That's a product designed by professional engineers and assembled in a factory. It's by no means a do-it-yourself ventilator, so it's not really applicable to your question, which was about lives saved by DIY ventilators, not production of them. In other words, the research you included didn't actually apply to the question you asked. And that was my basis for closing it.

But the important thing you need to keep in mind is that closed questions can be reopened. If you had simply told us what you "spent more than one day" looking for but couldn't find and told us *where* you looked, that would have met the requirements. You can still do so and I'll be perfectly happy to reopen it if you do. The community can also reopen it regardless of what I think.